# How to colour format a dataframe in R and export the table along with table headers and custom text into pdf?

Tags: r, pdf, datatable, r-markdown

I have created a dataframe in R based on multiple calculations and has columns (String  , 2 days average, 7 days average,Best average,Trend).

```
DF$String <- c("ABC", "XYZ", "DEA")
DF$`2 day average' <- c(0.4, 0.5, 0.6)
DF$`7 day average' <- c(0.5, 0.6, 0.7)
DF$`Best average' <- c(0.7, 0.9, 0.8)
DF$Trend <- c("Week", "Week", "Day")
```

I want to colour format column 2,3 and 4 with the same logic (background green if data>96%; yellow if between 90%-96%; red otherwise). I then want to add 2-3 lines of text above the table (as a report header) and print it in a pdf format with grids and colour formatting. I can't use XLConnect as I am repeatedly getting rJava issue. I want an easier way to go around this. Also this report will go out everyday so I just want to write a code that creates a pdf without any intervention.

I have tried this

```
customGreen = "#A9D08E"
customYellow= "#FFE700"
customRed = "#ff7f7f"
formattable(dataframe)

formattable(dataframe, 
            align =c("l","c","c","c"), 
            list(String = formatter(
              "span", style = ~ style(color = "black",font.weight = "bold"))))
```

Not sure how to colour the tiles according to the defined logic . I then need to 2-3 line of a header on top of the table and export into pdf. Can someone guide me through this?

Comment: The package  ```gt``` or maybe it's called ```gtable``` might be very helpful. It's here https://github.com/rstudio/gt, but you have to download and install from the zip file and it ends up named as gtable. There's a good video on it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1KAjSfSbmk

Comment: Hi @markhogue the nicely colour formatted table made through gt , is coming with basic grids when i convert it into pdf through rmarkdown. Do you know how to go around that?